# how to solve this complicated sql query

Tags: mssql-jdbc

these are the five given tables
http://i58.tinypic.com/53wcxe.jpg

this is the recomanded result
http://i58.tinypic.com/2vsrts7.jpg

please help how can i write a query to have this result.
no idea how!!!!

```
 SELECT K.*  , COUNT (A.Au_ID) AS AnzahlAuftr
 FROM Kunde K
 LEFT JOIN Auftrag A ON K.Kd_ID = A.Au_Kd_ID
 GROUP BY K.Kd_ID,K.Kd_Firma,K.Kd_Strasse,K.Kd_PLZ,K.Kd_Ort
 ORDER BY K.Kd_PLZ DESC;

 SELECT COUNT (F.F_ID) AS AnzahlFahrt
 FROM Fahrten F
 RIGHT JOIN Auftrag A ON A.Au_ID = F.F_Au_ID

SELECT SUM (T.Ts_Strecke) AS SumStrecke
FROM Teilstrecke T
LEFT JOIN Fahrten F ON F.F_ID = T.Ts_F_ID
```

how to join these 3 in one?

Comment: please help how can i write a query to have the same result in picture (result)!   http://i58.tinypic.com/2vsrts7.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping on Strasse etc. is not necessary and can be quite expensive. What about this approach:

```
SELECT K.*, ISNULL(Au.AnzahlAuftr,0) AS AnzahlAuftr, ISNULL(Au.AnzahlFahrt,0) AS AnzahlFahrt, ISNULL(Au.SumStrecke,0) AS SumStrecke
FROM Kunde K
LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT A.Au_Kd_ID, COUNT(*) AS AnzahlAuftr, SUM(Fa.AnzahlFahrt1) AS AnzahlFahrt, SUM(Fa.SumStrecke2) AS SumStrecke
FROM Auftrag A LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT F.F_Au_ID, COUNT(*) AS AnzahlFahrt1, SUM(Ts.SumStrecke1) AS SumStrecke2
    FROM Fahrten F LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT T.Ts_F_ID, SUM(T.Ts_Strecke) AS SumStrecke1
        FROM Teilstrecke T
        GROUP BY T.Ts_F_ID) AS Ts
    ON Ts.Ts_F_ID = F.F_ID
    GROUP BY F.F_Au_ID) AS Fa
ON Fa.F_Au_ID = A.Au_ID
GROUP BY A.Au_Kd_ID) AS Au

ON Au.Au_Kd_ID = K.Kd_ID
```

Comment: thanks alot from ur answer it looks very good but still not working,   error: Meldung 208, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 1
Ungültiger Objektname 'Aufrag'.

Comment: sorry i mean this error :Meldung 4104, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 13
Der mehrteilige Bezeichner 'Fahrten.F_Au_ID' konnte nicht gebunden werden.